# arg1 is not of type xs:anyAtomicType

Tags: xquery, marklogic

```
return
            fn:concat (fn:string-join ((
              "somevalue.1.",
              "somevalue.2.",
              "some val 3",
              "some val4",
              $somevariable), " "), 
 for $i in $loopvar    
              if ((fn:exists($loopvar)) and (fn:count($loopvar) > 1)) then
              " where ( "  || $loopvar[i] || " and "
              else if(fn:exists($loopvar) and (fn:count($loopvar) > 0)) then
              " where " || $loopvar[i]
              else() )
```

I m trying the above code but its giving me error at the fn:concat line. Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 1):

The fn:concat() function takes any number of single strings and not a sequence.

The fn:string-join() function concatenates sequences.

So, one solution would be to include the for loop in the sequence passed to string-join(), as in:

```
 fn:concat(fn:string-join((
     "somevalue.1.",
     "somevalue.2.",
     "some val 3",
     "some val4",
     $somevariable, 
     for $i in $loopvar
     return 
          if ((fn:exists($loopvar)) and (fn:count($loopvar) > 1)) then
          "where ( "  || $loopvar[i] || " and "
          else if(fn:exists($loopvar) and (fn:count($loopvar) > 0)) then
          "where " || $loopvar[i]
          else() )
     ), " ")
```

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Do I need to write the return statement before of after the for loop?  Because its giving me error that - unexpected If

Comment: Sorry, bad original code fragment.  Fixed.